# How to use data once the compute-shader is done?

Tags: directx-11

I have an output buffer in this format:

```
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC rgbaGPUBuffer;

rgbaGPUBuffer.ByteWidth             = width * height * 16; // 4 * 4 floats (RGBA)
rgbaGPUBuffer.Usage                 = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
rgbaGPUBuffer.BindFlags             = D3D11_BIND_UNORDERED_ACCESS | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
rgbaGPUBuffer.CPUAccessFlags        = 0;
rgbaGPUBuffer.MiscFlags             = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_BUFFER_STRUCTURED;
rgbaGPUBuffer.StructureByteStride   = 4; // shader will output one rgba component by one
```

I have an unordered access view:

```
D3D11_UNORDERED_ACCESS_VIEW_DESC descView;
descView.Format                     = DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN;
descView.ViewDimension              = D3D11_UAV_DIMENSION_BUFFER;
descView.Buffer.FirstElement        = 0;
descView.Buffer.NumElements         = rgbaGPUBuffer.ByteWidth / rgbaGPUBuffer.StructureByteStride;
descView.Buffer.Flags               = 0;
```

The buffer's usage MUST be `D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT` and CPUAccessFlags cannot be set. Therefore, the access's view format must be `DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN`. The irony is that once the compute-shader is finished, the output buffer actually holds the `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM` format. My render target swapchain is in that format and I cannot do anything with the data.

1. I cannot access it, because CPUFlags cannot be set.
2. I cannot copy because `CopyResource` doesn't work when the source and destination are not of the same Resource type.

**So, the question is, how to use this data?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their is a barrier between resources that the GPU can write, and the resource the CPU can read.

If you need a readback ( and break parallelism unless you add a few frame of latency from gpu work to cpu work ), the only way to do it is by creating a separate resource without the gpu binding in the `D3D11_USAGE_STAGING` pool and run a `CopyResource` to transfer your gpu work to the cpu accessible resource.

Comment: Does this scenario apply if my final goal is to transfer that data to the back buffer and call Present()? If yes, then I would have to move data from the GPU to the CPU and then again find a way to move it back to the back buffer. It makes me wonder how people use GPU for dumb operation like color conversion....

Comment: Of course not, if the work is of no interest for the cpu, then no. You can create your swap chain so the backbuffers are UAV, and you can have your compute directly writing them with a `RWTexture2D`. If more convenient, you can still separate the compute output and copy it back to the backbuffer with another compute or draw. I recommend you to not use a buffer for the destination like you did because they are less efficient on memory for texture read or write.

Comment: I understand generally what you are saying, but converting it to DirectX code is a nightmare because I'm an ignorant when it comes to DirectX. I will try to create a swapchain as you suggest, but I don't really know how to use `RWTexture2D` (or `Texture2D`) in the HLSL. I can ask a new question, so you can earn your reputation. Actually I don't even know how to create a swapchain, because current swapchain's usage is `DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT`. If I convert that to `DXGI_USAGE_UNORDERED_ACCESS`, will I be able to use it for presenting?

Comment: You just `OR` them for the swapchain usages : `DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT|DXGI_USAGE_UNORDERED_ACCESS`

Comment: Didn't know I'm allowed to combine usages with OR. Thanks!